# ERROR 1710 creating Hash index in memsql

Tags: singlestore

I tried creating hash index on my table in memsql using

`CREATE INDEX hashindex USING HASH ON table (column);`

But i get the following error

> ERROR 1710 (HY000): MemSQL does not support non-unique hash indexes.

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make that statement work, you would need to add the `UNIQUE` keyword between `CREATE` and `INDEX`. Ex:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX hashindex USING HASH ON table (column);`

If you are intentionally trying to have a non-unique hash index, however, it is not supported (as indicated in the error). If you are trying to have a unique index, then great! Adding the keyword will work for you. Just note that adding a unique index cannot be performed as an online operation.

Comment: what do you mean by online operation in                                                                   `Just note that adding a unique index cannot be performed as an online operation.`